# Difference between InputStream and InputStreamReader in java

Tags: java

I read that InputStream is used for byte based reading it reads 1 byte at a time. 
And InputStreamReader is used for character based reading so it reads one character at a time so no need to convert this first to int then read it.

Here is reading using InputStream.

```
 InputStream input=new FileInputStream("D:/input.txt");

 int c;

 while((c=input.read())!=-1)
 {
    System.out.print((char)c);
 }
```

here is reading using InputStreamReader

```
InputStream input=new FileInputStream("D:/input.txt");

reader=new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8");

int c;

while((c=reader.read())!=-1)
{
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

What is difference between `InputStream` and `InputStreamReader`? In both case I have to use a `int` and then read it and at the end if I want to print that data I have to cast that with "(char)c".

So what is advantage of using `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: The difference is that `InputStream` by itself won't handle input values greater than 127.  Try adding some Chinese characters to your test input, they'll print as two bytes with the `InputStream` version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a big difference between what is an `InputStream` and an `InputStreamReader`. One reads bytes whereas the other one reads character. Depending on the encoding used, one character may be more than 1 byte.

From [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--):

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream

From [`InputStreamReader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read--):

> Reads a single character.

`InputStreamReader` serves as a bridge between those two ways of reading data in Java: a way of bridging byte streams to character streams. [From its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html):

> An `InputStreamReader` is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted.
>
> Each invocation of one of an `InputStreamReader`'s `read()` methods may cause one or more bytes to be read from the underlying byte-input stream. To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But if this is the case then why both returning the same output. 
While displaying the output using System.out.println(c) i am getting same output for both.
Can you give any example so that i can see the difference practically.

Comment: @user3387084 Try reading a text in chinese ;), you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks @user3387084, so basically InputStreamReader should be used for encodings like "UTF-16". right ?

Comment: @user3387084 No, `InputStreamReader` should be used when you want to read characters using a certain encoding. For example, using UTF-8, you can read one chinese character at a time with a `Reader`. However, an `InputStream` needs to be used when you specifically want to read each byte of data.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki for the explanation, I was scratching my head.Now things are clear :)

Answer (score 1):

An **InputStream** is typically always connected to some data source, like a file, network connection, pipe etc. This is also explained in more detail in the Java IO Overview text.

**InputStreamReader** takes an inputstream and converts the bytes Strem into characters when you are reading it. For example, some UTF characters are 2 bytes, a call to an input stream reader will read the two bytes and convert it into a character automatically. It is used to read text streams.

Answer (score 0):

Some encodings have characters that span multiple bytes.  By reading with InputStream, you're stupidly reading the next byte as opposed to InputStreamReader that may read ahead as necessary in order to give you the next *character* as opposed to byte.  In other words, suppose you have 0x00 0xA7 as the next two bytes on the stream.  InputStream will give you 0x0 on first read and then 0xA7 on the next.  An InputStreamReader with unicode encoding will return you 0x00A7 on first read which is character §.

Please note that it is probably best if you wrap InputStreamReader with BufferedReader in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of InputStreamReader you can use 'char c' in place of 'int c' and instead of '-1' value, you can use 'null'. Like this :

```
InputStream input=new FileInputStream("D:/input.txt");

reader=new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8");

char c;

while((c=reader.read())!=null)
{
System.out.print(c);
}
```

Because you are using InputStreamReader which do character based reading.
 So, there is no need to set datatype 'int' and then to cast it using 'char', it is unnecessary.
We need to do this in the case of InputStream as it does byte based reading.